# delete duplicates in java arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

Thanks Marko. I rewrite the code. try to make it simple. this time it can really compile. but it can only delete duplicate items sit next to each other. for example, if i put in 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 1 -- the output is  1 2 3 4 5 1. it can't pick up the duplicate at the end. 
(BTW: new to this website, if make any display mess my apologies)

here's the new code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SetListDemo{
public static void main(String[] args){
    SetListType newList = new SetListType();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println( "Enter a series of items: ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    String[] original = input.split(" ");
    for (String s : original)
    newList.insert(s);

    List<String> finalList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(original)) ;

    Iterator<String> setIterator = finalList.iterator();  

    String position = null;

    while(setIterator.hasNext()){
        String secondItem = setIterator.next();

        if(secondItem.equals(position)){
            setIterator.remove();
        }   

        position = secondItem;
    }

    System.out.println("\nHere is the set list:");
    displayList(finalList);
    System.out.println("\n");
}

public static void displayList(List list){
    for(int index = 0; index <list.size(); index++)
    System.out.print(list.get(index) + ", ");
}

}
```

Comment: SetListType isn't a build-in class from Java. Is this a class you have written yourself or are you using the wrong class?

Comment: Please help us to know more about your code when you asked such question, what are SetListType and where does it come from ?

Comment: First of all thanks for all comments.

Comment: Please see my edited answer, I added a code example to show how it's done. Problem with your code is, that you only compare an item with the next one (secondItem = iterator.next()) no with all elements in the list. Thus, the first 1 is only compared with 2, not with all the following items. And the `List#contains()` method basically does exactly what wou tried to implement with your iteration and comparations.

Comment: Thanks Ridcully will have a trial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question "delete duplicates in java arraylist":

Just put all elements into a `Set` and you're done.

-or-

Iterate your `original` list and add the elements to a `List`, but before adding them, check with `List#contains()` if the element is already there.

**EDIT: Try this:**

```
String[] original = input.split(" ");
List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String s : original) {
    if (!finalList.contains(s)) {
        finalList.add(s);
    }
}

System.out.println("\nHere is the set list:");
displayList(finalList);
System.out.println("\n");
```

Comment: "Iterate your original list and add the elements to a List, but before adding them, check with List#contains() if the element is already there." yeah, that's really a shock for me. i just keep thinking about delete, delete. in fact i can remove unique items to a new list. thanks. wish i can meet the due day

Answer (score 3):

`SetListIterator` is a class indirectly referenced by your code, but it is not on the classpath. When setting up your project you forgot to copy that source file in addition to `SetListType`, or it could be that you are compiling this outside an IDE and simply failed to compile that class.

Comment: Thanks Marko. I rewrite the code. try to make it simple. this time it can really compile. but it can only delete duplicate items sit next to each other. for example, if i put in 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 1 -- the output is  1 2 3 4 5 1. it can't pick up the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

From what you're saying it sounds like when you run your assignment you are not setting your classpath correctly so that it includes the compiled class file of the SetListType.  You should be able to fix this by setting the `-classpath` option when running your main method to point to this and any other classes your assignment relies on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vector or ListArray and check if the element exists in the new list before you add it.

Just an example:

```
    Vector<String> list = new Vector<String>();
    System.out.println("list:");
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        list.add("" + new Random().nextInt(10));
        System.out.println(list.lastElement());
    }

    System.out.println("newList:");
    java.util.Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
    Vector<String> newList = new Vector<String>();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String s = it.next();
        if(!newList.contains(s)){
            newList.add(s);
        }
    }

    for(String s : newList){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

For the second part:

```
    int[] count = new int[newList.size()];      
    for(String s : list){
        int index = newList.indexOf(s);
        count[index]++;
    }

    for(String s : newList){
        System.out.println(s + " appears " + count[newList.indexOf(s)] + " times");
    }
```

Comment: First of all thanks for all comments. Yes SetListType is another class I write. it contains 8 methods: void insert(), E erase(E target), int count(E target)will be used to count the occurrences of elements in the original list, void clear(), boolean is Empty(), int capacity(), int size(), E get(int index); E remove(int index). We must use all of them to work out the program. tried to put a for loop  just before the <if> statement. but got illegalstartexception.