# ArrayList duplicates removal

Tags: java, date, arraylist, duplicates

I have an Arraylist with pings, these are dates linked to a name, I want to delete all duplicates of the names and keep the closest date of the name.

**Code**

```
private ArrayList <String> deleteDuplicates() {
  ArrayList <Ping> tempPings = new ArrayList < Ping > ();
  tempPings.addAll(jaws.pastMonth());
  for (int i = 0; i < tempPings.size(); i++) {
    Ping tempPing = tempPings.get(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < tempPings.size() - 1; j++) {
      Ping tempPing2 = tempPings.get(j);
      if (tempPing.getName().equals(tempPing2.getName())) {
        if (changePingToDate(tempPing2).before(changePingToDate(tempPing))) {
          tempPings.remove(j);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return pingToNames(tempPings);
}
```

changePingToDate() is a method to convert the date string into a gregorian calendar.

When I use this code it deletes a high proportion of the duplicates but there are still some remaining each time through the loop. I have also tried it without comparing the dates and still the same problem. Can anyone help?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @aribeiro Hi, I have checked that answer and it doesn't help with my question, my .equals seems to be working fine, the names are exactly the same e.g "Mary Lee" multiple times and it seems to pick and chose which ones to remove.

Comment: You are calling `.remove()`, which modifies the size of the list and **the index you are looking at** as you loop over it. You are skipping values.

Comment: Use an iterator. I don't want to add another answer here just for the sake of it. There are tons of resources available, both on SO and Google.

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok thank you, not completely sure I understand, if it is removing values after the one I'm comparing it to why does that change the index of the one I'm looking at? Have you any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Or dump all the values into a `Set` to remove duplicates.

Comment: I have added to answer to attempt at illustrating the point @cricket_007 was making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not remove elements from a list while looping inside of it. So add all items do you want to remove to another list and at the end remove all of them from the `tempPings`.

```
private ArrayList <String> deleteDuplicates() {
  ArrayList <Ping> tempPings = new ArrayList < Ping > ();
  tempPings.addAll(jaws.pastMonth());

  ArrayList <Ping> pingsToRemove = new ArrayList <Ping> ();
  for (int i = 0; i < tempPings.size(); i++) {
    Ping tempPing = tempPings.get(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < tempPings.size() - 1; j++) {
      Ping tempPing2 = tempPings.get(j);
      if (tempPing.getName().equals(tempPing2.getName())) {
        if (changePingToDate(tempPing2).before(changePingToDate(tempPing))) {

            pingsToRemove.add(tempPings.get(j));

        }
      }
    }
  }

  tempPings.removeAll(pingsToRemove);
  return pingToNames(tempPings);
}
```

Comment: You could use `Iterator.remove`

Comment: I have tried it this way and it ends up having, out of my 400 odd sized array, 9060 elements to remove, not sure at all why this has happened, if I were to use an iterator would that require the use of two? and I have never seen and implementation with an iterator of iterating past the already checked elements (in the case with for j = i + 1), is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Try to add an if statement before `pingsToRemove.add(tempPings.get(j));` to check if `tempPings.get(j)` has already added. Like `if(!pingsToRemove.contains(tempPings.get(j)))`.

Comment: This still contains the off-by-one issue caused by `for (int j = i + 1; j < tempPings.size() - 1; j++) {`.  If your list size if 10, your inner loop will loop while `j < 9`, any you will **never** compare any item to the `j = 9` item.  Your first loop could have be written `for (int i = 0; i < tempPings.size() - 1; i++) {`, the `- 1` is OK there because you start your second loop at `j = i + 1`, but it is not OK in the loop condition of the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayLiist<>(Arrays.asList(
        "apple",
        "banana",
        "grape",
        "banana",
        "apple",
        "banana",
        "apple",
        "grape"
));
```

Using Java 8?

```
values = values.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Only have Java 7?

```
values = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(values));
```

Output for both is

```
[apple, banana, grape]
```

Then just loop over the list like normal to do your date operation.

Comment: This would be very helpful, unfortunately we still have to compare the dates and leave the pings with unique names each and also the closest time. Thanks though, can see this being very handy in the future!

Comment: Just loop over the list after you remove the duplicates.

Comment: @cricket_007 What is the advantage of the stream over the second way with LinkedHashSet?

Comment: I want to say the stream is more memory efficient. The HashSet creates 2 intermediate data collections

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having issues understanding why the `remove()` op you are doing is causing an issue. I will try to explain.

*This is a generalized explanation, to give an idea about the issues in your code.*

I have a bucket of 10 things. On every iteration, I check to ensure that I am checking till `bucket.size()`. If I delete an item at `i`, the item at `i+1` takes it's place. The deletion process ensures that bucket.size() now equals 9, not 10. The loop increments my `i` by 1. The element that was at `i+1` and is now at `i` is skipped.

Comment: Makes so much more sense that way thank you very much!

Comment: @B.KLewis [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196762/delete-duplicates-in-java-arraylist) and [this post](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-remove-duplicates-in-a-list.html) demonstrate nice clean ways of using iterators to do this very thing.